# Password change: Best practice

Tags: database, security, authentication, web-applications

I'm writing Baby's First Web Application. My first task has been to set up an authentication system, which I think I've done okay on. I'm new to the whole thing, though, so:

When the user reports that he's forgotten his password, I e-mail him a temporary replacement password in plain text. It's perhaps not the most secure way to handle the situation, but it's how I do it for now. I do force him to change it at the next login, and the technique I use is to carry a "must-change" field in the database, set to true for users who've been sent the e-mail.

My question: Is a separate database column the best tactic under the circumstances, or is there something better I can do?

Comment: A separated column for the temporary replacement? Not 100% sure if I'm following your idea

Comment: A separate column called "mustchange". It defaults to false, and is set to true if the user must change his password immediately after the next login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A separate column is quite reasonable.

Operating systems typically have a "password expiration timestamp" field which doubles as a "must change at next logon" flag simply by setting the timestamp to 0 (AKA January 1, 1970). Web sites do not usually have password expiration dates, in which case a plain boolean flag suffices.

Comment: It's good to hear my approach is reasonable. I do try to think these things through, so I'm grateful for the affirmation.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are storing passwords hashed and salted. If not, do so. If so, you could store meta-data in the salt. E.g. the salt is `[0-9a-z]{8}`, but for temp passwords it is `____[0-9a-z]{4}`. (before downvoting, people, read on!) The point in this, is that a separate field might get edited separately from the hash field. Of course that *should* never happen, but it *can* happen. (failing queries, moronic sysadmins, people who have discovered phpmyadmin and *think* they understand the system, etc) Keeping the "state" of the password in the salt, prevents such mayhem: on validation of the password, you will always be able to see that you validated against a temp password, and you will *always* be able to identify the user who needs to get a "enter new password" prompt.

Comment: Interesting. I do hash the password, and I'll definitely look into the idea of salting it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My practice has always been to overload the email validation (where you send an email to the registrant to make sure that the registrant owns the address) to also function as a password reset mechanism. I use certain information about the user (username, id, email, **and importantly, the current password hash in DB**) to make a hash, which is included in a URL that's emailed to the user, at which point they can set a new password of their choosing.

That being said, the "best practice" vis-a-vis user authentication is 95% of the time to user a library that someone else has written and tested extensively. Just search Google for one that's appropriate for your framework.

Comment: Aha, e-mail validation! I hadn't considered that, but of course it's a common and sensible practice. Thanks.

As for using someone else's library: Certainly that's almost always a good idea. However, I'm at the stage now where I'm still trying to get my mind around all of the issues that are involved. To do that, I function best by writing some crude code myself and polishing it a bit as I go. I may well end up using an external library, though. The authentication wheel has been invented. I doubt I can make it any rounder.